# Materialize with Prestashop

Tags: css, prestashop, materialize

I'm new at programming with Prestashop and I'm trying to install a CSS framework in order to change the theme of my shop. The framework is called materializecss (https://materializecss.com/). The problem I have is that, my shop has a default theme which I want to just modify, and it has a css file called theme.css. What I want to do is to, for example, change my current buttons (from theme.css) for the ones of materializecss (which is another css file). Basically, I don't know how to join both css files in order to have my own theme.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to SO josembell! Unfortunately your question is too broad and open ended for SO. SO is better suited to specific coding questions in Q&A format. A good rule of thumb is that SO questions should almost always involve some code in the question. I recommend you ask this question in a forum or relevant subreddit. For now I'm flagging to close.

Comment: take a look at prestashop docs https://devdocs.prestashop.com/?_ga=2.39263334.431475626.1544020686-1052515929.1542724775